# How to delete table view row from custom cell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a custom table view cell with two buttons. If either one is pressed, I want the table view to delete the row. I already know the code for that:

```
myArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

I just would like to call this from my custom cell. I have it set up like so:

```
@IBAction func handleDecline(sender: AnyObject)
{
    // Remove table view row 
}

@IBAction func handleApprove(sender: AnyObject)
{
    // Remove table view row
}
```

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not handle deletion of a cell from the cell itself. It violates MVC pattern. Events should be delegated to the view controller and handled there with `deleteRows` method like this:

```
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

Also tableView's dataSource must be updated accordingly, otherwise app will crash.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40111943/1689376) you can find an example of how you can delegate an event from cell to view controller

Comment: That example doesn't seem to be working. Perhaps it's outdated?

Comment: My apologies, I fixed the minor syntax changes and now it works.