# addTarget for button in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm trying to add the download button for some items in my tableView. I've created the custom cell class and added the label and the button outlets, everything is working in displaying the info and even the buttons are showing where it should be.

I'm trying to add the target, but it does nothing. I need to pass the row index to the buttonClicked function or should I create this function in the custom cell class and then do the action some how? I would like to know the best practise of this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlaylistCell", for: indexPath) as! PlaylistTableViewCell

        let playlist = self.playlists?[indexPath.row]

        cell.titleLabel.text = playlist?.getTitle()


        if (playlist?.isOfflineAvailable())! {
            cell.downloadButton.isHidden = false
        } else {
            cell.downloadButton.isHidden = true
            cell.downloadButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.downloadButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }

        return cell
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        let buttonRow = sender.tag
        print(buttonRow)
    }
```

I've also tried removing the (sender:) from #selector, but it does not change a functionality.

Comment: You can also add IBAction to your cell and call a delegate method there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40111943/1689376

Comment: Thanks, I really needed this!

Comment: You're welcome. In fact there is nothing wrong with target-action approach. Check the answer below for details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to handle button callback in your view controller, you have two choices:

**Target-action:**

Add target-action in `cellForRow` method just as you did. Your code is probably not working because you are hiding the button when it should be visible, aren't you?

I guess you need to replace this

```
if (playlist?.isOfflineAvailable())! {
    cell.downloadButton.isHidden = false
} else {
    cell.downloadButton.isHidden = true
    cell.downloadButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.downloadButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

With this:

```
cell.downloadButton.isHidden = playlist?.isOfflineAvailable()
cell.downloadButton.tag = indexPath.row
cell.downloadButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

You should update tag every time because cell are reused in `tableView` and if don't do it every time when `cellForRow` is called, you may easilly get a case when a callback is called but it's tag belongs to indexPath from the previous cell usage. Also I've changed `isHidden` logics to the opposite. I guess you should hide the button when `isOfflineAvailable` returns true, right?

**Delegate pattern**

It is described a million of times here on SO and on many other sites as well. Basically you define a cell protocol, implement it in your controller and send callbacks from cell to it's delegate whenever a button is pressed. You can find more details in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40111943/1689376) for a similar question.