# pass data from custom cell(in table which is on ViewController) to the viewcontroller itself Swift3 iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, custom-cell, pass-data

I have a `ViewController`. The `ViewController` has a `TableView` in it.
The `TableView` has a few custom cells (say one is with the `DatePicker`, second is `TextField`, third is whatever it is - that's not the case) - cells are described in a `TableViewCell`

So, I'm pressing the one with `DatePicker`, set the date "**01.01.2016**" on cell

ISSUE: I need to insert "**01.01.2016**" into a dictionary which is in the **ViewController**

would appreciate any advice
thanks

Comment: Is it the case that user  selects any button after he has finished interaction with the tableview? or do you need to get the picker data as soon its value is changed?

Comment: Check my answer about how you should use delegate pattern to pass events and data from cell to viewController: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40111943/1689376

Comment: Rakshith yes the last one as soon as its value is changed

Answer (score 1):

Create `internal` variables on your viewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // Keeping an internal reference to your datePicker
    internal var datePicker: UIDatePicker?
    // Keeping an internal reference to the indexPath, where you have the datepicker
    internal var datePickerIndexPath: IndexPath?
    // Your dictionary, where you want to save the date
    internal var dictionary: [String: Any] = [:]
```

Assign the `datePicker` and the `indexPath` in `cellForRowAt`, when you are dequeuing that cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Dequeuing cells and some other logic

        // Assign the cell's datePicker to the internal datePicker
        self.datePicker = cell.datePicker
        self.datePickerIndexPath = indexPath
}
```

And in the `didSelectRowAt` function, just use the internal variables and your dictionary

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let datePickerIndexPath = self.datePickerIndexPath, datePickerIndexPath == indexPath {
            dictionary["date"] = self.datePicker?.date
        }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a delegation method in the ViewController that the custom TableViewCells call when the date selection happens. The ViewController can assign itself as the cell's delegate in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: To clarify: will there be multiple DatePickers? Or is there only one such TableViewCell and consequently only one date to remember?

Comment: might be several pickers but one per cell