# How to implement Cosmos star rating using delegates?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

In a UITableView with 2 sections and I'd like to implement [CosmosView star rating](https://github.com/evgenyneu/Cosmos).
In the first section I create a prototype cell and assign it to a custom class `FeedbackCell`

Then I implement a `protocol ClassFeedbackCellDelegate` which must provide `DetailViewController` with the cell that was tapped.
  The problem is that I don't get the rating value in `DetailViewController` in `func sharePressed(cell: FeedbackCell)`. I implemented the protocol based on this answer. [how to call presentViewController from within a UICollectionViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40111778)
    Please guide me on how to implement this rating control correctly.

```
protocol ClassFeedbackCellDelegate {
   func sharePressed(cell: FeedbackCell)
}

class FeedbackCell: UITableViewCell {

  var delegate: ClassFeedbackCellDelegate?
  @IBOutlet weak var cosmosViewBelongingToFeedBackCell: CosmosView!
  @IBOutlet weak var submitButtonOutlet: UIButton!

  @IBAction func submitFeedBack(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.sharePressed(cell: self)
   }
}




 class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContentCell")
     let feedbackCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedbackCell") as? FeedbackCell
    feedbackCell?.delegate = self  //assign self as the delegate

    if bookingCompleted && indexPath.section == 0 {

        //default rating when tableView loads for first time
        feedbackCell?.cosmosViewBelongingToFeedBackCell.rating = 4
        return feedbackCell ?? UITableViewCell()
    }

        (cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel)?.text = titles[indexPath.row]
        (cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as? UILabel)?.text = titlesToValues[titles[indexPath.row]]
           return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
  }
}

extension DetailViewController: ClassFeedbackCellDelegate {

 func sharePressed(cell: FeedbackCell) {
     print("sharePressed was called ")// prints out
     cell.cosmosViewBelongingToFeedBackCell.didFinishTouchingCosmos = {
      rating in
            print("rating here in extension is \(rating)")//doesn't print out
     }
   }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> // Called when user finishes changing the rating by lifting the finger from the view.
>   cosmosView.didFinishTouchingCosmos = { rating in }

So when `sharePressed(cell: FeedbackCell)` is called, the user has already lifted his finger so this doesn't suit your need.

Instead, you can probably just do this:

```
func sharePressed(cell: FeedbackCell) {
    print("sharePressed was called ")// prints out
    print("rating: \(cell.cosmosViewBelongingToFeedBackCell.rating)")
}
```

Also, you should save the rating somewhere as the rating will be reset if the user scrolls the table view.

**Edit:**

If you want to keep track of the current rating, you can modify the protocol and add the listener to the `FeedbackCell`:

```
protocol ClassFeedbackCellDelegate {
   func sharePressed(cell: FeedbackCell)
   func ratingDidChange(rating: Float)
}

class FeedbackCell: UITableViewCell {

  var delegate: ClassFeedbackCellDelegate?
  @IBOutlet weak var cosmosViewBelongingToFeedBackCell: CosmosView!
  @IBOutlet weak var submitButtonOutlet: UIButton!

  @IBAction func submitFeedBack(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.sharePressed(cell: self)
   }

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    cosmosViewBelongingToFeedBackCell.didFinishTouchingCosmos = {
      rating in
        self.delegate?.ratingDidChange(rating)
     }
  }
}
```

Then in `DetailViewController`:

```
extension DetailViewController: ClassFeedbackCellDelegate {
  func ratingDidChange(rating: Float) {
    print(rating)
  }
}
```

Comment: Should `IBAction func submitFeedBack` reside in the `FeedbackCell` or in `DetailViewController`? I would like to create same behaviour as in the native UIPickerView. For example when the user lifts his finger off cosmosView, I should be able to receive the star rating inside `DetailViewController`. Basically I would need to get a reference from the cosmosView that is in `FeedbackCell` to `DetailViewController`, so that I could do `cosmosView.didFinishTouchingCosmos = { rating in // use the value here}` Thank you

Comment: now that I have the `rating` in `DetailViewController`, how should I pass it back to `@IBAction func submitFeedBack(_ sender: Any)` so that I can send it to my server?

Comment: @bibscy You can save the rating in DetailViewController and send to server when submitFeedback is called.

Comment: I saved the rating in DetailViewController, but submitFeedback belongs to class FeedbackCell. How can I observe from DetailViewController when submitFeedback is tapped?

Comment: @bibscy Sorry, should be sharePressed in DetailViewController.