# How to activate share extension (UIActivityViewController) when a button tapped (which is in UICollectionViewController)?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uiactivityviewcontroller

[image]

I'm trying to add some buttons or labels to one of UICollectionViewCell, but it seems I'm not be able to activate UIActivityViewController when the share button tapped.

Here are my codes:

```
class VerticalCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {




 override init(frame: CGRect) {

    super.init(frame: frame)


    containerView.addSubview(shareButton)
    shareButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    shareButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: favoriteButton.leftAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    shareButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true
    shareButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true
    shareButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleShareButton), for: .touchUpInside)

}

  @objc func handleShareButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let shareText = NSLocalizedString("I found something interesting you may want to take a look at.", comment: "share")
        let shareImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Bear")
        let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText, shareImage as Any], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



}
```

The errors are: 
`Value of type 'VerticalCollectionViewCell' has no member 'view'` 
and 
`Value of type 'VerticalCollectionViewCell' has no member 'present'`.

I know presentViewController is a UIViewController method, UITableViewCell does not has a method called presentViewController, and UITableViewCell should never handle any business logic. It should be implemented in a view controller.

But I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you call do in this way

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet let shareButton: UIButton!
}
class VC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? Cell {
            cell?.shareButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(VC.shareButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
    }
    func shareButtonPressed(_ button: UIButton) {
        //code here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is define a protocol of the cell, which your tableview can conform to. When the share button on a collectionView is tapped, call this delegate method, passing in relevant information like the cell tag or the model for that collectionView cell. Using that information you can then present the ActivityController from your viewController.

Comment: Thanks, Rakshith. You mean like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40111778/how-to-call-presentviewcontroller-from-within-a-uicollectionviewcell ?